# parse date (Format: "15DEC2017:01:00:00")

Tags: r, date, data.table, tidyverse, fread

I want to import a csv-file with dates in the following format: 15DEC2017:01:00:00.
As the file is quite heavy (2 GB) I'm using data.table::fread() which does not recognize the values as dates/datetimes. It is treated as characters instead. How can I import (or convert) the values to a date format (or date-time)?

```
dates <- c("15DEC2017:01:00:00", "01DEC2017:15:30:00")
df <- data.frame(dates, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
class(df$dates)
[1] "character"
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: df$dates2 <- lubridate::dmy_hms(df$dates)

Comment: Base R: `as.POSIXct(dates, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(dates = anytime(dates))
#              dates
#1 2017-12-15 01:00:00
#2 2017-12-01 15:30:00
```